# Listview items not displaying the retrieved columns from database vertically

Tags: java, android

Using simple cursor adapter I retrieve 5 columns from a table using cursor query and display them using a listview. Everything goes well but the columns retrieved are displayed horizontally in the listview. I want them to be displayed one below the other like:
TX_UID
TX_NAME
TX_AMOUNT
TX_PARTICULARS

AND NOT LIKE (Displayed as of now):
TX_UID  TX_NAME  TX_AMOUNT  TX_PARTICULARS

```
String[] from = new String[]{  vivzHelper.TX_UID,     
vivzHelper.TX_NAME,vivzHelper.TX_AMOUNT,vivzHelper.TX_PARTICULARS};
int[] to = new int[] 
{R.id.textView,R.id.textView2,R.id.textView3,R.id.textView5 };
SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),  
R.layout.customgetalltxrowforeditordelete , c , from , to , 0);
thislist.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
thislist.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

XML Layout:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
android:divider="#FFCC00"
android:dividerHeight="2px"
android:smoothScrollbar="true"
android:background="@drawable/my_selecter"
/>
```

Comment: keep your textview vertically in customgetalltxrowforeditordelete layout

Comment: post customgetalltxrowforeditordelete code

Comment: It is posted already for that particular area wherein the list view is raised using simple cursor adapter. I get the view but in horizontal manner which should be made to appear vertically one below the other.

Answer (score 2):

> columns retrieved are displayed horizontally in the listview. I want
>   them to be displayed one below the other

Problem is related to `customgetalltxrowforeditordelete` layout instead of `ListView`.
To show TextView's in ListView row Vertically. use `LinearLayout` with `orientation` attribute to `vertical`

Comment: I dont have problems like this in my other activities for ListView inside Relative Layout. However as said by you I used with orientation attribute 
to 'portrait' in manifest file for this activity, but no use.

Comment: @user3144078: not in manifest file set it in `customgetalltxrowforeditordelete`

Comment: @user3144078: and if you are using `Relative Layout` then use `layout_below` for align view in vertical way

Comment: My 'listview' component is not within 'customgetalltxrowforeditordelete'. It is in an activity. In the java class I use this in activity file  'myactivity.xml' and with 'customgetalltxrowforeditordelete.xml' custom file I pass the columns from adapter.

Comment: @user3144078: please show `customgetalltxrowforeditordelete` file

Comment: Well, the 'customgetalltxrowforeditordelete.xml' file was in Linear Layout and the corresponding Listview holding activity file was in 'Relative Layout' and that was the error. I changed the 'customgetalltxrowforeditordelete.xml' to Relative layout and now it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

In your customgetalltxrowforeditordelete  xml file you need to do something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:src="@drawable/badge13"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_below = "@id/textView"

   />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@id/textView3"
    android:layout_below = "@id/textView2"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@id/textView4"
    android:layout_below = "@id/textView3"
    />
```

you need to use layout_below attribute in your TextView providing top view's id in attribute.

Comment: Yes, I have used layout_below attribute but not getting display one below the other.

Comment: do one thing, add text attribute inside every TextView and write a dummy message so that you can see in your ide the proper orientation of texts.

Comment: <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@id/textView4"
    android:text="Dummy1"
    android:layout_below = "@id/textView3"
    />